# Yii2. Создание миграций

Tags: php, yii2, миграция

Друзья, столкнулся с некоторой проблемой.
Необходимо создать 3 таблицы в БД (brand,model,equipment) с применением связей через инструмент миграций Yii2.

Таблицы плана: Марка -> Модель -> Комплектация.

Если создаю внешние ключи сразу на первом этапе, то получаю ошибку об отсутствии следующей таблицы (т.к. мы ее еще не создали, что логично).

Как проще всего создать миграцию с обновлением полей в существующих таблицах? Быть может есть дефолтные функции для этого?

Т.е. делаю три миграции для создания структуры необходимых таблиц, а четвертой миграцией связываю первую таблицу со второй (один ко многим) и вторую таблицу с третьей (один ко многим).

Comment: Почему бы не создать сначала третью таблицу, потом вторую со связью на третью, а потом первую со связью на вторую?

Comment: А это ведь гениально, сегодня попробую, спасибо. Так далеко мой мозг не заходил

Comment: И не нужно 3 миграции. Делайте в одной.